# thread_queue_size during Live Streaming from ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I'm trying to stream a webcam stream froma RaspberryPi-B to Youtube. The webcam used is a Logitech C920. If I use the h264 stream from the camera itself, it works fine using

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1,0 -f v4l2 -vcodec h264 -video_size 854x480 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -acodec aac -b:a 64000 -ar 48000 -bufsize 64k -b:v 1200k -bufsize 1024k  -maxrate 1800k -vcodec copy -g 60 -r 30 -f flv
 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_here
```

So, for this to work with other non h264 cameras like the Pi Cam or any other cheaper webcam, it needs to work with the raw stream and get converted to h264 using libx264. This is the whole point of using the Pi. Hence the second command set.

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1,0 -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720  -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_name
```

So this results in the following issue.

```
ffmpeg version git-2017-03-03-68ee800 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --arch=armhf --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --extra-libs=-lasound --enable-pthreads
  libavutil      55. 47.101 / 55. 47.101
  libavcodec     57. 82.100 / 57. 82.100
  libavformat    57. 66.103 / 57. 66.103
  libavdevice    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavfilter     6. 74.100 /  6. 74.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:1,0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1488650966.446293, bitrate: 1024 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 2227.042654, bitrate: 159252 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 864x480, 159252 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x2e42310] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
Illegal instruction
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

If I add

```
thread_queue_size 512
```

I end up with

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1,0 -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 512 -i /dev/video0 -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720  -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/zqg7-98wy-60b6-f2yx
ffmpeg version git-2017-03-03-68ee800 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --arch=armhf --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --extra-libs=-lasound --enable-pthreads
  libavutil      55. 47.101 / 55. 47.101
  libavcodec     57. 82.100 / 57. 82.100
  libavformat    57. 66.103 / 57. 66.103
  libavdevice    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavfilter     6. 74.100 /  6. 74.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:1,0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1488651430.836193, bitrate: 1024 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 2691.407641, bitrate: 159252 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 864x480, 159252 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Illegal instruction
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Where exactly does

```
thread_queue_size
```

Belong?

Notes: 
ffmpeg was built using this [reference](http://hannes.enjoys.it/blog/2016/03/ffmpeg-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi/#comment-5052)
–extra-libs=-lasound & --enable=pthreads was used

Comment: `Illegal instruction` suggests ffmpeg has been compiled with the wrong arch target. Your `thread_queue_size` placement is fine.

Comment: This happens only when I goto encode from raw to x264. If I directly use the h264 stream from the camera it works fine. ffmpeg was compiled for armhf according to the guide I followed. could it be that x264 was not conpiled properly?

Comment: That seems likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I totally forgot that the RaspberryPI had hardware support for H264.

So I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/legotheboss/YouTube-files/wiki/(RPi)-Compile-FFmpeg-with-the-OpenMAX-H.264-GPU-acceleration) and we're live on 30% CPU usage with realtime streaming on the Raspberry Pi B (ARMV6).